# ImportError during CircleCI test

Tags: python-2.7, circleci

I tried to find a solution for this problem but I didn't find anything.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named mock)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/client/tests/test_gs_interface.py", line 23, in <module>
    import unittest, mock, kiss
ImportError: No module named mock
```

When I make a test with CIrcleCI using default parameters I always get the same ImportError.

I read at the documentation that I must set the configuration manually but I didn't find how to do.

Anybody could tell me how to import a module in the circle.xml configuration file?

Thank you.

Comment: Samuel. This is Kim from CircleCI. Could you post the question in our support with the URL to the failed build? We can give you better support there. Thanks,
Kim

Comment: Thanks Kim, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Is `mock` included in your `requirements.txt` file? Also, do you have a Python version specified in your `circle.yml` file, as suggested [here](https://circleci.com/docs/language-python#version)?

Comment: Neither of them. Thanks for the info.